# How to calculate BLEU Score without the brevity penalty

Tags: nlp, nltk, machine-translation, bleu

**code:**

```
import nltk
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu 
score1 = sentence_bleu(ref1, cand)
```

How can I ignore brevity penalty from the BLEU score calculated here?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code in NLTK, you can see the brevity penalty is hardcoded in the computation, just before the final score is returned, on the following line.

```py
s = bp * math.exp(math.fsum(s))
```

You can surely copy and modify the source code. There is also the `breivity_penalty` function, which allows you to compute it yourself and divide the score again.

Also, be aware that the implementation of BLEU in NLTK is different from the original reference implementation that was recently fully replicated in the [sacrebleu](https://github.com/mjpost/sacreBLEU) package. The main problem is that the reference implementation of BLEU used non-standard tokenization rules which NLTK does not implement. All current machine translation literature reports BLEU scores using sacrebleu.

With sacrebleu, you can get the sentence level BLEU like this:

```py
import sacrebleu
bleu = sacrebleu.sentence_bleu("I am the walrus.", ["I am the walrus."])
```

The output is a tuple that contains the final score as well as the individual components: the n-gram precisions and the brevity penalty.